# Upload image via Django admin

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models, django-admin

At the moment I am working on a Django project for a scholarship using Django 1.6.4. I would like to upload some images to my apache server. Unfortunately, I was not able to overcome the "Permission denied" message after filling out the form in the admin page. My project is located under `/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/`. There is my virtualenv directory and my real project called `kleyboldt_homepage` located (`kleyboldt` is the name of the guy I am writing for). My model looks like this:

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/homepage/models.py**:

```
class stipendiat(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content     = models.TextField()
    year        = models.IntegerField()
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='stipendiaten/', default='default.jpg')
```

My settings are:

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/kleyboldt_homepage/settings.ps**:

```
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static-only')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
```

and

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mks.com python-path=/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage:/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mks.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /robots.txt /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static-only/favicon.ico

    <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|css|gif|pdf|ico)$">
        SetHandler None
    </LocationMatch>

    Alias /media/ /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static-only/

    Alias /static/admin /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static-only/admin/

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/media>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static-only>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt.wsgi

    ServerName mks.com

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Files /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/homepage.log>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/apache_error.log
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry that I wrote so much but I wanted to be sure that I did not forget a directory.

mks.com is redirected to my local machine with an entry in `/etc/hosts`.

The permissions for my media directory are:

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 nick www  4096 Mai 20 13:21 media
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this error?

Comment: Is the "permission denied" a Django 403 response when you try to submit the form, or a filesystem permission denied traceback on the Python function that writes your file on the disk?

Comment: It was a Django response. I solved the issue by changing the group to www-data instead of www.